# iOS - Why the Popup window is auto clicked without any code been written to click?

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium

[Popup imageScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odu09.jpg)

-When user taps on an element, a Popup window is seen.

-This popup window has two buttons - OK and Cancel - Attached is the screen shot

-The automation script always clicks on Ok button (but there is no code written to do so)

Code:

```
        System.out.println("The below line clicks on an element to get   the popup");                 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[1]/UIAStaticText[1]")).click();
       //There is no further code, which is return to click on any element
```

**Wired** thing is - If i disconnect my device after running the script, and try to do it manually again. The popup will be auto clicked on OK button again. Something to do with the script.
If i reinstall the app, the functionality is fine,not a defect from app side

**Appium version i am using**: 1.5.3

**Machine** - Apple Mac OS

**Device** - iPhone SE 9.3OS

This is the kind of problem i am also facing , but not finding any solution https://discuss.appium.io/t/autoacceptalerts-true-clears-all-alerts-when-testing-the-app/5721/2

Answer (score 0):

Check your desired capabilities once.

if you have the below code then it will accept everytime

**capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);**

OR

**capabilities.SetCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);**

Comment: Yes i do have one of them, i figured it out its happening b'c of that. But i need that desired capabilities for few of the alert popup to be either accepted / dismissed when my app launch. But later on in other pages of the App, i need to handle it separately in code depends on my test conditions. How to do that ?

Comment: Is there an option to either disable that Capabilities later in my script , i did try to Use capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", false); but it still performs it as True conditions ? Is there a way to reset that capabilities?

Comment: @Lokesh Don't set any value for the above two capabilities. Just don't add them in you capabilities. And you can either handle them separately or let appium handle , but you can not do the same things with same capabilities. I suggest , better handle the pop ups every time as they come separately.

Comment: Thanks, Will do that. But was wondering is there any other way or method to do it